# Wayfinder not working on new Evo install

Tags: modx, modx-evolution, wayfinder

Ive just installed Evo 1.0.13 and am trying to get wayfinder working.

I have copied the contents of `wayfinder.inc.php` in the snippets/wayfinder folder to a new snippet as the instructions dictate and have added:

```
[[Wayfinder? &amp;startId=`0` &amp;level=`2`]]
```

but nothing appears.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault. I should have been copying the content of `snippet.wayfinder.php` not `wayfinder.inc.php`